# Gnome Terminal: How to open up multiple tabs, execute commands and return to zsh/bash

Tags: bash, terminal, zsh, gnome, gnome-terminal

I'm trying to automate my morning start up process. Often I'll start multiple running scripts that I will exit (using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>) and restart manually as needed.

So I'm looking to create a bash script that

1. Starts `gnome-terminal`
2. Opens some tabs and executes a number of
   commands
3. Returns back to zsh upon exit or completion of the script so I can
   manually enter more commands

Currently I have,

```
#!/bin/bash

gnome-terminal \
--tab -t "Server" -e "bash -ic \"cd ~/Dev/server; npm start; exec zsh\"" \
--tab -t "Framework" -e "bash -ic \"cd ~/Dev/framework; npm start; exec zsh\"" \
--tab -t "Client" -e "bash -ic \"cd ~/Dev/client; npm start; exec zsh\"" \
--tab -t "Admin" -e "bash -ic \"cd ~/Dev/admin;npm start; exec zsh\""
```

The problem with this solution is that tabs may or may not jump back into zsh. Sometimes 3 tabs will, sometimes one. Ideally I'd like all 4 to go back into zsh.

If anyone could help me around this, I'd be grateful.

Comment: Why not set your shell to `zsh`?

Comment: My shell is set to `zsh` by default. I was trying to `exec zsh` at the end of each tab to replace the closing `bash -ic` commands so they dont exit

Answer (score 0):

You can take `gnome-terminal` out of the equation and it still won't work:

```
bash -ic "npm start; bash"
```

Press Control-C, and you won't get a shell. For `bash`, we can get around this problem using the `--rcfile` option:

```
bash --rcfile <(echo "npm start")
```

This way we don't read the real `.bashrc`, so since we probably want to read that, let's modify this a bit:

```
bash --rcfile <(echo ". ~/.bashrc; npm start")
```

For zsh on the other hand it doesn't work with the equivalent(?) `--rcs` option, but it does when started with the `ZDOTDIR` variable. So we create a `.zshrc` for each of `~/Dev/server`, `~/Dev/framework`, `~/Dev/client`, `~/Dev/admin` with the following content:

First:

```
. ~/.zshrc
cd ~/Dev/server
npm start
```

Second:

```
. ~/.zshrc
cd `~/Dev/framework`
npm start
```

etc.

Your `gnome-terminal` command will look like this:

```
gnome-terminal \
--tab "Server" -e "sh -c 'ZDOTDIR=/path/to/directory/containing/first/.zshrc'" \
--tab "Framework" -e "sh -c 'ZDOTDIR=/path/to/directory/containing/second/.zshrc'"
# etc
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried both solutions, `bash --rcfile` and the `ZDOTDIR=~/.../.zshrc`, however they both didn't seem to work. I used the second ~/Dev/framework/.zshrc example and the `gnome-terminal` with 1 tab. **The results of starting:** 
`bash node.sh` - Warning: DESKTOP_STARTUP_ID not set and no fallback available.
`zsh node.sh` - Same as bash
`sh node.sh` - Aliased to bash on my machine (fedora)

Comment: Hmm, what's `node.sh`? Can you give me your Fedora version and your gnome-terminal version?